# Error in mounting rootfs in android

Tags: linux, filesystems, embedded, android

Failed to `make` and `chown /acct/uid_0`:

> Read-only file system

I have a i.xm6q sabresd reference board and another is a development board based on i.mx6.

I'm trying to port Android O on development board and I have almost got it but I get so many of these errors,

```
[    7.066508] random: watchdogd: uninitialized urandom read (40 bytes read)
[    7.075946] watchdogd: watchdogd started (interval 10, margin 20)!
[    7.089698] EXT4-fs (mmcblk0p3): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: barrier=1
[    7.146760] random: tune2fs: uninitialized urandom read (40 bytes read)
[    7.285261] random: tune2fs: uninitialized urandom read (40 bytes read)
[    7.368367] tune2fs: tune2fs 1.43.3 (04-Sep-2016)
[    7.368367] 
[    7.377979] EXT4-fs (mmcblk0p10): Ignoring removed nomblk_io_submit option
[    7.390407] EXT4-fs (mmcblk0p10): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: errors=remount-ro,nomblk_io_submit
[    7.463106] random: e2fsck: uninitialized urandom read (40 bytes read)
[    7.494389] random: e2fsck: uninitialized urandom read (40 bytes read)
[    7.662366] e2fsck: e2fsck 1.43.3 (04-Sep-2016)
[    7.662366] 
[    7.668482] e2fsck: Pass 1: Checking inodes, blocks, and sizes
[    7.668482] 
[    7.675830] e2fsck: Pass 2: Checking directory structure
[    7.675830] 
[    7.682633] e2fsck: Pass 3: Checking directory connectivity
[    7.682633] 
[    7.689749] e2fsck: Pass 4: Checking reference counts
[    7.689749] 
[    7.696309] e2fsck: Pass 5: Checking group summary information
[    7.696309] 
[    7.703632] e2fsck: userdata: 11/315120 files (0.0% non-contiguous), 55023/1260032 blocks
[    7.703632] 
[    7.724024] EXT4-fs (mmcblk0p10): Ignoring removed nomblk_io_submit option
[    7.736138] EXT4-fs (mmcblk0p10): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: nomblk_io_submit,noauto_da_alloc,errors=panic
[    7.752848] EXT4-fs (mmcblk0p4): Ignoring removed nomblk_io_submit option
[    7.765317] EXT4-fs (mmcblk0p4): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: nomblk_io_submit
[    7.787667] EXT4-fs (mmcblk0p9): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: barrier=1
[    7.838798] random: fast init done
[    7.908721] zram0: detected capacity change from 0 to 314572800
[    7.977162] mkswap: Swapspace size: 307196k, UUID=90d23762-1dcf-4195-945c-5aca95fcb0f2
[    7.986869] Adding 307196k swap on /dev/block/zram0.  Priority:-1 extents:1 across:307196k SS
[    7.987717] logd.auditd: start
[    7.987749] logd.klogd: 7963870334
[    8.134332] binder: 1393:1393 ioctl 620a 33c57e62 returned -22
[    8.404796] logd.daemon: reinit
[    8.634235] type=1400 audit(8.600:6): avc: granted { read } for pid=1 comm="init" name="ttymxc0" dev="tmpfs" ino=1145 scontext=u:r:init:s0 tcontext=u:object_r:tty_device:s0 tclass=chr_file
[    8.697581] type=1400 audit(8.600:6): avc: granted { read } for pid=1 comm="init" name="ttymxc0" dev="tmpfs" ino=1145 scontext=u:r:init:s0 tcontext=u:object_r:tty_device:s0 tclass=chr_file
[    8.715766] type=1400 audit(8.600:7): avc: granted { read open } for pid=1 comm="init" path="/dev/ttymxc0" dev="tmpfs" ino=1145 scontext=u:r:init:s0 tcontext=u:object_r:tty_device:s0 tclass=chr_file
[    8.733728] type=1400 audit(8.600:7): avc: granted { read open } for pid=1 comm="init" path="/dev/ttymxc0" dev="tmpfs" ino=1145 scontext=u:r:init:s0 tcontext=u:object_r:tty_device:s0 tclass=chr_file
[    8.751507] type=1400 audit(8.630:8): avc: granted { read } for pid=1468 comm="init" name="ttymxc0" dev="tmpfs" ino=1145 scontext=u:r:init:s0 tcontext=u:object_r:tty_device:s0 tclass=chr_file
[    8.770114] type=1400 audit(8.630:8): avc: granted { read } for pid=1468 comm="init" name="ttymxc0" dev="tmpfs" ino=1145 scontext=u:r:init:s0 tcontext=u:object_r:tty_device:s0 tclass=chr_file
[    8.799949] type=1400 audit(8.630:9): avc: granted { read open } for pid=1468 comm="init" path="/dev/ttymxc0" dev="tmpfs" ino=1145 scontext=u:r:init:s0 tcontext=u:object_r:tty_device:s0 tclass=chr_file
navico_6dq:/ $ [    8.859894] healthd: unable to get HAL interface, using defaults
[    8.868377] healthd: No battery devices found
[    8.872812] healthd: battery l=100 v=0 t=42.4 h=2 st=2 chg=a
[   13.370447] init: starting service 'netd'...
[   13.375873] init: Failed to make and chown /acct/uid_0: Read-only file system
[   13.377373] init: Created socket '/dev/socket/netd', mode 660, user 0, group 1000
[   13.378034] init: Created socket '/dev/socket/dnsproxyd', mode 660, user 0, group 3003
[   13.378621] init: Created socket '/dev/socket/mdns', mode 660, user 0, group 1000
[   13.379162] init: Created socket '/dev/socket/fwmarkd', mode 660, user 0, group 3003
[   13.414039] init: createProcessGroup(0, 1619) failed for service 'netd': Read-only file system
[   13.423010] init: property_set("ro.boottime.netd", "13351604334") failed: property already set
[   13.661802] init: starting service 'mediaextractor'...
[   13.668095] init: Failed to make and chown /acct/uid_1040: Read-only file system
[   18.375988] init: starting service 'netd'...
[   18.381839] init: Failed to make and chown /acct/uid_0: Read-only file system
[   18.383204] init: Created socket '/dev/socket/netd', mode 660, user 0, group 1000
[   18.383858] init: Created socket '/dev/socket/dnsproxyd', mode 660, user 0, group 3003
[   18.384471] init: Created socket '/dev/socket/mdns', mode 660, user 0, group 1000
[   18.385035] init: Created socket '/dev/socket/fwmarkd', mode 660, user 0, group 3003
[   18.421917] init: createProcessGroup(0, 1732) failed for service 'netd': Read-only file system
[   18.431026] init: property_set("ro.boottime.netd", "18357515002") failed: property already set
[   18.668197] init: starting service 'mediaextractor'...
[   18.674552] init: Failed to make and chown /acct/uid_1040: Read-only file system
[   20.117228] capability: warning: `main' uses 32-bit capabilities (legacy support in use)
[   23.384442] init: Created socket '/dev/socket/netd', mode 660, user 0, group 1000
[   23.392732] init: Created socket '/dev/socket/dnsproxyd', mode 660, user 0, group 3003
[   23.401652] init: Created socket '/dev/socket/mdns', mode 660, user 0, group 1000
[   23.410060] init: Created socket '/dev/socket/fwmarkd', mode 660, user 0, group 3003
[   23.674667] init: starting service 'mediaextractor'...
[   23.680775] init: Failed to make and chown /acct/uid_1040: Read-only file system
[   23.688421] init: createProcessGroup(1040, 1871) failed for service 'mediaextractor': Read-only file system
[   23.698493] init: property_set("ro.boottime.mediaextractor", "23656648336") failed: property already set
[   23.708514] init: starting service 'wificond'...
[   23.714374] init: Failed to make and chown /acct/uid_1010: Read-only file system

developmet_6dq:/ $
```

I see these errors:

```
init: Failed to make and chown /acct/uid_1040: Read-only file system
```

#### Questions

1. I don't know where to look for to solve and debug it.
2. I can do su and get root access, but why its not mounted as root?